# Replacement of System.drawing in developing windows 8 apps

Tags: c#, image, windows-8, drawing

Can any one tell me what is the replacement of System.Drawing in developing windows 8 apps. I tried System.Drawing but it is not supported by windows 8 apps. I have to use Image.FromFile() but it is showing error in windows 8. It is working fine in console application.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this article from MSDN might help you out: [**XAML vector-based drawing sample**](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Drawing-bfc39296).

The sample covers:

- Drawing basic shapes using the Rectangle , Line , Ellipse , and Polygon classes.
- Applying Stroke and Fill values to define the appearance of the outline and interior of the shape.
- Applying a LinearGradientBrush fill. Clipping elements by setting the Clip property.
- Drawing complex, compound shapes using Path elements that contain various shapes, figures, and Bezier curves.

**Edit:**

Instead of the System.Drawing namespace, for Windows 8 there is the [**Windows.Graphics.Imaging namespace**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.graphics.imaging.aspx). If you follow the link you'll find several samples/articles explaining how to [**process image files**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465080.aspx), how to [**encode**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj709935.aspx) (file from image) or [**decode**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj709934.aspx) (image from file) or how to [**edit an image**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj709937.aspx).

Hope this helps you out further! :)

Comment: Actually I need System.Drawing.Imaging because i am converting a .tiff image into jpeg formet in windows 8 RT. But System.Drawing.Imaging is not supporting in Windows 8 RT apps. That's why i need a replacement of System.Drawing or System.Drawing.Imaging in Windows 8 RT. If there is any such library so please update me.

Comment: hii, Please check my code it is not working properly. I used the namespce that you told. It is ok but the code is not working please check it and tell me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I used the namespace Windows.Graphics.Imaging and tried to convert my tiff image into jpeg but it is not working. pls check the following code and tell me what i am doing wrong in the code.

```
                        Image myImage = new Image();
                        var stream = await image.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
                        var bitmapImage = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
                        await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(stream);
                        myImage.Source = bitmapImage;
                        var decoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
```

Comment: You have to load the file from somewhere: through a FilePicker or a path to the image...

Comment: Yes i am loading a image .                             FileOpenPicker openPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
openPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.ComputerFolder;
openPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".tif");
StorageFile image = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

Comment: I think it's time you move this to a separate question. Explain what you want to achieve and show the code you already have. Also explain what's not working or what errors you get. That way you'll get better response than placing pieces of code in comments. :)