# Image processing library for windows 8 App Store

Tags: c#, image-processing, windows-8

I am developing a `Windows 8 Store App` with C# and I need to do some image processing like *filter by color, detect circle*, etc...

Normally I can do it with `AForge.Net` library in .Net project but with Windows Store App it is impossible to use this library as it does not allow System.Drawing namespace.

Any idea for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacement of System.drawing in developing windows 8 apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317014/replacement-of-system-drawing-in-developing-windows-8-apps)

Comment: It's better if you tell the people behind AForge.NET to support Window Store Apps or try to support it yourself (given that is open source, you can try to do it), also you may want to look for alternatives (I know none).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A while ago I refactored *AForge.NET Framework* to *Portable Class Libraries*, targeting .NET 4.5 and higher, Windows Store apps and Windows Phone 8 and higher. I have managed to port most of the functionality so far, except the *Video* and *Robotics* libraries. The image processing library is fully supported.

You'll find my *AForge.NET* port [here](https://github.com/cureos/aforge).

I have also ported most of the companion *Accord.NET Framework* to PCL, same targets. You'll find *Portable Accord.NET* [here](https://github.com/cureos/accord).