# Sharpdx load bitmap fom file Windows 8 apps

Tags: c#, sharpdx

I've found this example in SharpDX "BitmapApp" samples:

```
public static Bitmap LoadFromFile(RenderTarget renderTarget, string file)
    {
        // Loads from file using System.Drawing.Image
        using (var bitmap = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(file))
        {
            var sourceArea = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);
            var bitmapProperties = new BitmapProperties(new PixelFormat(Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm, AlphaMode.Premultiplied));
            var size = new Size2(bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);

            // Transform pixels from BGRA to RGBA
            int stride = bitmap.Width * sizeof(int);
            using (var tempStream = new DataStream(bitmap.Height * stride, true, true))
            {
                // Lock System.Drawing.Bitmap
                var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(sourceArea, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);

                // Convert all pixels 
                for (int y = 0; y < bitmap.Height; y++)
                {
                    int offset = bitmapData.Stride*y;
                    for (int x = 0; x < bitmap.Width; x++)
                    {
                        // Not optimized 
                        byte B = Marshal.ReadByte(bitmapData.Scan0, offset++);
                        byte G = Marshal.ReadByte(bitmapData.Scan0, offset++);
                        byte R = Marshal.ReadByte(bitmapData.Scan0, offset++);
                        byte A = Marshal.ReadByte(bitmapData.Scan0, offset++);
                        int rgba = R | (G << 8) | (B << 16) | (A << 24);
                        tempStream.Write(rgba);
                    }

                }
                bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
                tempStream.Position = 0;

                return new Bitmap(renderTarget, size, tempStream, stride, bitmapProperties);
            }
        }
    }
```

But my problem is that only works for wpf or deskop application.

I want to build a Windows Store app but System.Drawing doesn't exist any longer.
It has been replaced by Windows.Graphics.Imaging ([Replacement of System.drawing in developing windows 8 apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317014/replacement-of-system-drawing-in-developing-windows-8-apps))

I'm a beginner and I dont know how to make this function works with windows 8.

This function was perfect for me because I want to load a .png file and then I want to transform it. I tried and it works in the BitmappApp samples.

```
RenderTarget2D.Transform = Matrix.Transformation2D(center, 0f, new Vector2(500 / _bitmap.Size.Width, 900 / _bitmap.Size.Height), center, 0f,Vector2.Zero);
RenderTarget2D.DrawBitmap(_bitmap, 1.0f, BitmapInterpolationMode.Linear);
```